# How to find the record for the minimum value of a field when grouped by another field in BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am currently working on BigQuery standart SQL.
I want to find the the value1,value2,value3 fields for the minimum value of date field when the records are grouped by col1. In the following example, row1 and row2 have the the same date. So picking any one of them is fine.

[image]

The output should look like this-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can consder below using [HAVING MIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate-function-calls#having_min)

```sql
SELECT ANY_VALUE(t HAVING MIN PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', date)).*
  FROM sample_table t
 GROUP BY t.col1;
```

**Query result**

[image]